# Does direct microscopic examination help detect contamination during sample collection in clinical bacteriology?

Tags: bacteria, diagnostics, microbiology

*Background information*

Direct microscopic examination (or Direct smear) typically refer to microscopic examination of a specimen before any culture or inoculation is performed.

*Question*

Can direct smear help detect contamination of clinical samples during sample collection (e.g. contamination of blood culture by skin flora during venipuncture)?

*Prior Research*

"A situation in which three different morphotypes (cellular types) are seen on direct Gram stain, but more than three organisms are on the culture plate indicates possible contamination."
(**Bailey & Scott's Diagnostic Microbiology, 13th edition.**)

Does this "contamination" refer to contamination in-lab contamination post direct smear, where the number of culture isolates > morphotypes?

Or, does it refer to contamination prior to direct smear, where the contaminant biological count was insignificant to be noticed by microscope but they grew after culturing?

Comment: I think it would help if you explained your motivation for asking this question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and it would depend highly on what sort of sample you were taking, but in general, yes.

The reasons for this are that a smear on a slide should only (through statistical odds) pick up common organisms, which, assuming you have sampled correctly should be the disease causing ones. Contaminants should, *in theory at least*, be at a lower abundance, so less likely to be sampled

In addition, because a Gram stain is differential only really for Gram +/- (size can play into it too, but differentiating the species of say *Streptococcus* is impossible by Gram stain), you can't necessarily tell if two or more species are present in the sample.

For example, say you took a throat swab sample from someone complaining of a sore throat. You put some onto a blood plate and do a quick Gram slide too. On the slide you see small spherical Gram + bacteria. You think great - *Streptococcus*. However in culture you also see small greyish-white, non-hemolytic colonies and larger white, B-hemolytic colonies.  In this example, the grey, non-hemolyitc colonies would be *[Staphylococcus epidermidis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staphylococcus_epidermidis)* and the hemolytic colonies would be Group A *[Streptococcus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streptococcus_pyogenes)*. *S. epidermidis* is normal skin microflora that wouldn't normally be found in the throat, and is usually only pathogenic around things like ports and lines, so a likely contaminant.